# Only increase height or width using pinch gesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, xcode4.5, uipinchgesturerecognizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using UIPinchGestureRecognizer to scale uiviews in single direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759028/using-uipinchgesturerecognizer-to-scale-uiviews-in-single-direction)

**My code is below:**

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *croperViewGessture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(croperViewScale:)];
        croperViewGessture.delegate=self;
        [croperView addGestureRecognizer:croperViewGessture];   

     -(void)CanvasScale:(id)sender
{
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        if ([sender numberOfTouches] == 2) {
            _pntOrig[0] = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:cropedAngle];
            _pntOrig[1] = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:cropedAngle];
        } else {
            _pntOrig[0] = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:cropedAngle];
            _pntOrig[1] = _pntOrig[0];
        }
        _lenOrigX = fabs(_pntOrig[1].x - _pntOrig[0].x);
        _lenOrigY = fabs(_pntOrig[1].y - _pntOrig[0].y);
        _xScale = 1.0;
        _yScale = 1.0;
    }
    if ([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if ([sender numberOfTouches] == 2) {
            CGPoint pntNew[2];
            pntNew[0] = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:cropedAngle];
            pntNew[1] = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:cropedAngle];

            CGFloat lenX = fabs(pntNew[1].x - pntNew[0].x);
            CGFloat lenY = fabs(pntNew[1].y - pntNew[0].y);

            CGFloat dX = fabs(lenX - _lenOrigX);
            CGFloat dY = fabs(lenY - _lenOrigY);
            CGFloat tot = dX + dY;

            CGFloat pX = dX / tot;
            CGFloat pY = dY / tot;

            CGFloat scale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
            CGFloat dscale = scale - 1.0;
            _xScale = dscale * pX + 1;
            _yScale = dscale * pY + 1;
        }
    }
CGAffineTransform transform = cropedAngle.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTarnsform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, _lenOrigX, _lenOrigY);
[cropedAngle setTransform:newTarnsform];
```

}

But problem is that when I do Zoomin OR Zoomout then view spread on all over the screen and after it disable Please view my code and tell me what is wrong .

Please help me in this issue 
i am Thankfull in advance.

Comment: you have to implement the code in `croperViewScale:` not `CanvasScale:` or change this line  `UIPinchGestureRecognizer *croperViewGessture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(croperViewScale:)];`  to `UIPinchGestureRecognizer *croperViewGessture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(CanvasScale:)];`

Comment: Sory, both or same i mean to say both are the same functions name my funtion name is canvasScale i have to implment now correct place

Comment: sorry,I cannot found any specific solution with this please give me any other way to solve that problem i have already so much time spent on this issue otherwise thanks you for giving time.............Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own custom extension to `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to provide an `xScale` and a `yScale`, in addition to the normal `scale`. This is a drop in replacement for `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. You now have the option of looking at the normal `scale` or the new `xScale` and `yScale`. Use these values accordingly to scale your view based on how the user does the pinch gesture.

RMPinchGestureRecognizer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface RMPinchGestureRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint _pntOrig[2];
    CGFloat _lenOrigX;
    CGFloat _lenOrigY;
    CGFloat _xScale;
    CGFloat _yScale;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat xScale;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat yScale;

@end
```

RMPinchGestureRecognizer.m

```
#import "RMPinchGestureRecognizer.h"

@implementation RMPinchGestureRecognizer

@synthesize xScale = _xScale;
@synthesize yScale = _yScale;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if ([self numberOfTouches] == 2) {
            CGPoint pntNew[2];
            pntNew[0] = [self locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            pntNew[1] = [self locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];

            CGFloat lenX = fabs(pntNew[1].x - pntNew[0].x);
            CGFloat lenY = fabs(pntNew[1].y - pntNew[0].y);

            CGFloat dX = fabs(lenX - _lenOrigX);
            CGFloat dY = fabs(lenY - _lenOrigY);
            CGFloat tot = dX + dY;

            CGFloat pX = dX / tot;
            CGFloat pY = dY / tot;

            CGFloat scale = [self scale];
            CGFloat dscale = scale - 1.0;
            _xScale = dscale * pX + 1;
            _yScale = dscale * pY + 1;
        }
    }
}

- (void)setState:(UIGestureRecognizerState)state {
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if ([self numberOfTouches] == 2) {
            _pntOrig[0] = [self locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            _pntOrig[1] = [self locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
        } else {
            _pntOrig[0] = [self locationInView:self.view];
            _pntOrig[1] = _pntOrig[0];
        }
        _lenOrigX = fabs(_pntOrig[1].x - _pntOrig[0].x);
        _lenOrigY = fabs(_pntOrig[1].y - _pntOrig[0].y);
        _xScale = 1.0;
        _yScale = 1.0;
    }

    [super setState:state];
}

@end
```

Comment: @ Thanks Rmaddy: i am new in ios please can u tell me how to use it in my code which i show above.

Comment: +1. Liked this solution compared to the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759028/using-uipinchgesture-to-scale-uiviews-in-single-direction

Comment: @ACB Thanks. That other solution isn't very reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html)

Your line `CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scaleTemp,scaleTemp);` uses the same `scaleTemp` variable to modify both the x and y values of the transform.

Comment: Thnaks Adam ! When I cahnge here then, The view disable and after it not show so please give me any example that solve my issue

Comment: You'll need to do some calculations.  A similar question has been asked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759028/using-uipinchgesture-to-scale-uiviews-in-single-direction

Comment: this question is also same problem, When i use it and try to solve then it become again in my problem first it only rotate in y direction after solution it also increase both height and width not seprately that my problem OTherwise thanks for giving time have you any other solution so please tell me....................Thanks

Comment: Every one that will do this problem use this tutorial[1]: https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView