# How to make a image resizable crop box

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to find a way to create a box on top of the user uploaded picture so that the user can crop the picture to fit X cropping aspect ratio (the box would have a X min width&height and defined aspect ratio of the box).

I was able to find repos that play with cropping boxes but none that have aspect ratio functions. thus I was wondering if anyone can point me to a tutorial so that I could learn how to do that or a repo that would do what I want to achieve so that I could see how another person achieved that.

Comment: If I understand you correctly what you want to do is let the user crop the image but with the aspect ratio that you want and you initially provide the crop box with that particular aspect ratio. If that's the case why don't you restrict ability to resize crop box to resizing only by same scale in both X and Y directions thus maintaining the initial aspect ratio? I hope I have made myself clear here.

Comment: Yes, thats what I would like to do. but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: How are you letting users resize the cropbox? I did something similar recently where I used `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to let users resize. If you are doing the same, you can check out `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` section here http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more. The idea is to set both X and Y scales to same value in `CGAffineTransform`.

Comment: @zambrey Could you share the code that you used to resize with pinch? please

Comment: Hey Johnathan, Did you solved it? I can't find anything ah

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of challenges here, one is the UI to present and drag a cropping control, the simpler one is the math to constrain the cropping control.  Here's a hint on the latter:

```
@interface CropBox : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect box;
@property (assign, nonatomic)  CGFloat aspect;  // set this to 16.0/9.0=1.77 e.g. to get 16:9

- (void)setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin;
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width;
- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height;

@end

@implementation CropBox

- (void)setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin {

    self.box = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, self.box.width, self.box.height);
}

- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width {

    CGFloat height = width / self.aspect;
    self.box = CGRectMake(self.box.origin.x, self.box.origin.y, width, height);
}

- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height {

    CGFloat width = height * self.aspect;
    self.box = CGRectMake(self.box.origin.x, self.box.origin.y, width, height);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot share my exact code publicly. But this is how it went roughly. In my case I wanted to allow resizing a UIImageView with pinch. In your case this could be a simple rectangle. If so, just the logic in `handlePinch:` function would change accordingly. 
Initializing pinch gesture recognizer and adding it to the targeted view.

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[imageview addGedtureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

Actual gesture handler code. For the gesture handler code I have referred [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) page.

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{    
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;    
}
```

In case of `CGRect` resizing you should look into `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` method on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) page. Second and third arguments in CGAffineTransformScale are scaling factors in X and Y directions respectively. The crucial thing in maintaining the aspect ratio same as initial value would be having these both values same.
Hope this helps. Do comment in case I haven't made something clear.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom UIPinchGestureRecognizer that can scale in either single direction or both.  This could be used to do a custom scale of the overlaid crop view.  You may be able to adapt some of the settings to help in your project.  Check it out at; https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938469/1186235